# How to Serialize an OpenTelemetry Javascript Span

Tags: javascript, node.js, open-telemetry

Question: Is there any code that can take an [OpenTelemetry JS](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js) span object (as received by an exporter) and transform it into an object that has *just* its telemetry data and not internal implementation details?

That is -- if I have an exporter like this

```
    class FileSpanExporter {
      constructor() {
        this.stream = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/telemetry.log', {flag:'a'})
      }
      export(spans, resultCallback) {
          this.stream.write(JSON.stringify(spans))
          if(resultCallback) {
            return resultCallback({ code: core.ExportResultCode.SUCCESS });
          }
      }
    }
```

The span(s) that get written to the the log include data I'd consider telemetry data

```
    "attributes": {
      "express.name": "query",
      "express.type": "middleware"
    },
    // ...
    "endTime": [
      1622658683,
      606307380
    ],
    // ...
```

but also includes data that's implementation details

```
    "_spanProcessor": {
      "_spanProcessors": [
        {
          "_exporter": {
        // ... way more data snipped ...
```

Does the open telemetry javascript code have any way to serialize a span to get *just* its telemetry data?  Or is that something that's the responsibility of the end-user-programmer to decide which data they are/aren't interested in before exporting.  All I've been able to find so far is the `span.context()` method, which returns *only* the context information, but not other pertinent data.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for something similar to this https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/blob/main/packages/opentelemetry-tracing/src/export/ConsoleSpanExporter.ts. This is explicitly designed for debugging purposes and not a great choice for actual applications.

Comment: +1 -- thank you for the information. The functionality in the `_exportInfo` method of that class is the example sort of thing I'm looking for, but I'm looking for whether there's a public/supported API for doing this, or if it's up to each exporter to do it's own serializing before sending the data on.

Comment: It is upto the each exporter to encode and serialize.

Comment: Have a look at the Jaeger and Zipkin exporters as well. They both have their own serialising functions to convert a ReadableSpan into their native representations.